# Configuring an astable 555 timer to milliseconds

Tags: clock, 555, timer, computers

I am working on a Tinkercad project and I would like a 555 astable clock for it. I am trying to configure the astable 555 timer for every millisecond (or something close). I don't know how to do it, can one of you teach me?

Comment: What are you trying now?  1 kHz is very doable for a 555.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, please. Show us what you got so far, and where exactly you are stumbling.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the basic circuit of the LM555 ?   It is a very simple circuit.
Made with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110)
Don't forget the 1 uF capacitor ... [link](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555_oscillator.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The circuit you want is called an astable multivibrator.  The 555 datasheet has a section named Astable Operation.  In it there is a complete schematic and the equations needed to calculate the component values.

There also is a chart relating ranges of component values to operating frequency, so you can select approximate component values without any math.